Is it possible to use one property of an object to inform the type of another
tl;dr I am wondering if there is a way to do what the as K does in the following pseudo-typescript:
interface Foo { 
  model: (keyof Models) as K, 
  data:  typeof Models[K] }
}

I suspect the answer is no, but one can always hope.
If some elaboration would help, suppose I have a bunch of interfaces describing db models, collected like this:
interface Models {
  Table1: { t1Prop: string }
  Table2: { t2Prop: number }
  // ...etc
}

Now suppose I have a collection of fixtures in an object like this:
const fixtures = [
  {
    model: 'Table1',
    data:  { t1Prop: 'hello' }
  }, 
  {
    model: 'Table2',
    data: { t2Prop: 1 }
  }
]

Is there a way to make it so typescript expects each fixture's data to either contain a t1Prop string or a t2Prop number depending on what its model is set to?

• Is there some reason you're writing typeof Models instead of just Models? The former only makes sense if Models is a value and not just an interface. Maybe you should [edit] to remove typeof there? • I'd say you want Foo to be a union, and you can make one from Models via a distributive object type as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

Oh sorry, the typeof Models is just a mistake on my part. Updated.

That does seem to do what I want! Wow, I never would have thought to have a type that both defines a mapped type and then becomes the set of all values in that type. It kind of twists my brain in a knot, but it's very cool. Thanks!
